# SQL Server to Big Query DDL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new to big query and finding ways to migrate all the table structures from SQL Server to Big Query. There were close to 300 tables that needs to be created. Is there any way to do this automated or do in less time. Kindly throw some light on it as I presume many would have done this task.

Thanks in advance,

Venkat.

Comment: There are not a direct GCP tool to perform this migration. Although, I find this [article](https://medium.com/datamindedbe/import-sql-server-data-in-bigquery-d640441d5d56) may be useful for you to figure out the best practice in your case.

Comment: Why you want to move from SQL Server to BigQuery? Is your current database big?

Comment: Yes data is big and we need to do some live reporting and multiple other reasons

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for this? I have the same problem right now.

Comment: @Kc2 We are currently using dataflow template to run the batch jobs, you can edit the jdbctobigquery template to include as many pipelines you require. they run simultaeneously. let me know if you find any better way.

Comment: If the big query editor allowed DDL statements you could script out your SQL tables and alter the syntax (i.e. data types) and run them in the BQ UI... if enough people star this request we might get it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151714664

Answer (score 0):

I recenty wrote a blog post about the subject

https://ael-computas.medium.com/copy-sql-server-data-to-bigquery-without-cdc-c520b408bddf

I also released a package on pypi that you can use as a base for your integrations

```
from database_to_bigquery.sql_server import SqlServerToCsv, SqlServerToBigquery
sql_server_to_csv = SqlServerToCsv(username="scott",
                                   password="t1ger",
                                   host="127.0.0.1//optionalinstance_name",
                                   database="thedb",
                                   destination=f"gs://gcsbucketname")

bigquery = SqlServerToBigquery(sql_server_to_csv=sql_server_to_csv)

result = bigquery.ingest_table(sql_server_table="table_to_read",
                               sql_server_schema="dbo",
                               bigquery_destination_project="bigqueryproject",
                               bigquery_destination_dataset="bigquerydataset")
print(result.full_str())
```

Just getting the schema could be something like this.

```
columns, pks = sql_server_to_csv.get_columns("table", "dbo")
bigquery.write_bigquery_schema(columns, "/path/to/file")
# /path/to/file can be in cloud storage, ie - gs://foo/bar.json
```

It does make some assumptions on datatypes, that you might want to override, and that is entirely possible.